# 'oppose a strong negative'

Tags: word-usage, grammar

I saw that he thought the information was important, and to my suggestion that we put an additional lock on the east wing door he [**opposed a strong negative.**](http://www.online-literature.com/mary-rinehart/circular-staircase/18/)

I thought the above expression somehow odd.

Is it a natural expression in English?

Comment: What is the source of this quote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote is from the story "[The Circular Staircase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Circular_Staircase)" by Mary Roberts Rinehart, and seeing that it was written in 1908, the language usage is somewhat archaic in nature.

The full quote is as follows:

> I told him of the experience Louise Armstrong had had the night
>   before, on the circular staircase, and about the man who had so
>   frightened Rosie on the drive. I saw that he thought the information
>   was important, and to my suggestion that we put an additional lock on
>   the east wing door **he opposed a strong negative**.
>
> "I think it probable," he said, "that our visitor will be back again,
>   and the thing to do is to leave things exactly as they are, to avoid
>   rousing suspicion. Then I can watch for at least a part of each night
>   and probably Mr. Innes will help us out. I would say as little to
>   Thomas as possible. The old man knows more than he is willing to
>   admit."

In context, the sentence doesn't mean that the man is opposed, or against, the 'strong negative', but rather, he is putting up a strong opposition against the idea of putting another lock on the east wing door, for the reasons given in the following paragraph.

In modern day usage this sentence structure does indeed seem unnatural - we generally oppose *someone* or *something*, rather than use it to mean '*counter with*', as it's being used in this example.

Answer (score 1):

When I read this (as a native English speaker) the phrase did seem odd;it feels like a run on sentence. I would not say this is a natural expression.

Answer (score -1):

Your sentence though strange sounding has a clear meaning

> He opposed a strong negative
>   *he opposed strong countermeasures*

The sentence does not mean he opposed the suggestion *per se* but he opposed anything being changed to stop the event from happening again.

> [negative](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/negative) (*v*) - to neutralize or counteract

is being used as a verb in the legal sense of the word.  In the story the writer is proposing action which would stop the event from happening again, whereas the detective thinks "the thing to do is to leave things exactly as they are, to avoid rousing suspicion" and was hoping to witness the act first hand the following night.

Your sentence means

> He opposed a strong action to stop the event from happening again.